# Does the Samsung tablet 3 SM-T211 have USB host mode OTG support?

Tags: usb-host-mode, usb-on-the-go, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-7

Does the Samsung tablet 3 SM-T211 have USB host mode OTG support? If not, is there a way to enable / support it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab-accessories/EPL-AU10WEGXAR-compatible) and this [review](http://reviews.cnet.com/tablets/samsung-galaxy-tab-3/4864-3126_7-35755712.html) (down near the end of the review), the 8" and 10" Galaxy tab 3s have OTG, but apparently the 7" does not. It might be possible to enable it by rooting and installing an app for it, but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

At least one of the USB devices would need support for host-mode USB - which is a hardware feature and therefore can't be upgraded via software - and the other needs to report as mass storage USB device.

Since your tablet has OTG (=host-mode USB) support it may be a simply compatibility issue. Bluetooth may be an option, but it's slow.